# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 25 What was this error meant

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

When I run the below program it producing the errors can any tell me the solution for this
I need to pass the data to my database using the parameters in method InsTable :

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.util.*;
public class InsertusrProf
{
public static Connection prepareConnection()throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
    String dcn="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@JamesPJ-PC:1521:skypark";
    String usname="system";
    String pass="tiger";
    Class.forName(dcn);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url,usname,pass);
}
public static void InsTable(String uname,String photo1,String video1,String    music1,String notes1,String messages1,String link,String frd,String cmt,String lik,String     ulik,String shrs,String qst,String answ,String updt,String thms,String wrd,String comm,String grp,String pgs,String ntfcn,String rqst,String tps,String tg)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException,FileNotFoundException
{
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(1024);;
    sb.append("insert into ").append(uname).append("(PHOTO,VIDEO,MUSIC,NOTES,MESSAGES,LINKS,FRIENDS,COMMENTS,LIKES,UNLIKES,SHARES,QSTNS,ANS,UPDATES,THEMS,WORDS,LANGUAGES,RELEGION,PRIVACY,HOBBIES,FAV,QULIFICATION,COMMUNITIES,GRPS,PAGES,NOTIFICATION,REQUESTS,TIPS,CITY,TAG)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    String stmnt=sb.toString();
    Connection con=prepareConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(stmnt);
    ps.setString(1,uname);

    File fl=new File(photo1);
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fl);
    ps.setBinaryStream(2,fis,(int)fl.length());

    File fl1=new File(music1);
    FileInputStream fis1=new FileInputStream(fl1);
    ps.setBinaryStream(3,fis1,(int)fl1.length());

    File fl2=new File(video1);
    FileInputStream fis2=new FileInputStream(fl2);
    ps.setBinaryStream(4,fis2,(int)fl2.length());

    File fl3=new File(shrs);
    FileInputStream fis3=new FileInputStream(fl3);
    ps.setBinaryStream(12,fis3,(int)fl3.length());

    File fl4=new File(updt);
    FileInputStream fis4=new FileInputStream(fl4);
    ps.setBinaryStream(15,fis4,(int)fl4.length());

    File fl5=new File(notes1);
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(fl5);
    //BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(notes1.getCharacterStream());
    ps.setCharacterStream(5,fr,(int)fl5.length());

    File fl6=new File(messages1);
    FileReader fr1=new FileReader(fl6);
    ps.setCharacterStream(6,fr1,(int)fl6.length());

    ps.setString(7,link);

    ps.setString(8,frd);

    File fl7=new File(cmt);
    FileReader fr2=new FileReader(fl7);
    ps.setCharacterStream(9,fr2,(int)fl7.length());

    ps.setString(10,lik);

    ps.setString(11,ulik);

    File fl8=new File(qst);
    FileReader fr3=new FileReader(fl8);
    ps.setCharacterStream(13,fr3,(int)fl8.length());

    File fl9=new File(answ);
    FileReader fr4=new FileReader(fl9);
    ps.setCharacterStream(14,fr4,(int)fl9.length());

    ps.setString(16,thms);

    File fl0=new File(wrd);
    FileReader fr5=new FileReader(fl0);
    ps.setCharacterStream(17,fr5,(int)fl0.length());

    ps.setString(18,comm);

    ps.setString(19,grp);

    ps.setString(20,pgs);

    File fls=new File(ntfcn);
    FileReader fr6=new FileReader(fls);
    ps.setCharacterStream(21,fr6,(int)fls.length());

    ps.setString(22,rqst);

    File fls1=new File(tps);
    FileReader fr7=new FileReader(fls1);
    //BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(tps.getCharacterStream());
    ps.setCharacterStream(23,fr7,(int)fls1.length());

    ps.setString(24,tg);

    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println("<<<<<<<Record Inserted Successfully>>>>>>> Count :"+i);

    con.close();
}
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    String uname="james";
    String photo1="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/img1.jpg";
    String video1="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/How To Make 3D Text In Photoshop (ADOBE PHOTOSHOP CS6 TUTORIAL).flv";
    String music1="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/Lelepadi.mp3";
    String notes1="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String messages1="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String link="aaaaa";
    String frd="bbbb";
    String cmt="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String lik="asadssfds";
    String ulik="zxzxxzcx";
    String shrs="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/img1.jpg";
    String qst="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String answ="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String updt="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/img1.jpg";
    String thms="bgfvdft";
    String wrd="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String langs="erdgdfgf";
    String rlgn="bngfhgfh";
    String prvc="zxcsdw";
    String hbs="bgnbvc";
    String fvt="tgfhfghjfgh";
    String qlf="mklkopi";
    String comm="mbnfchgeshgw";
    String grp="bgyeadb";
    String pgs="hfhfj";
    String ntfcn="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String rqst="ghfhgfh";
    String tps="C:/Users/James P J/Documents/javaprog/test.java";
    String cty="jjkhgjghjk";
    String tg="qwewr";
    InsTable(uname,photo1,video1,music1,notes1,messages1,link,frd,cmt,lik,ulik,shrs,qst,answ,updt,thms,wrd,comm,grp,pgs,ntfcn,rqst,tps,tg);
}
  }
```

I tried to solve this error by making the mode as IN OUT in procedure what i created
But the following error was not solved if any solution find please answer for it.
The Error was :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at
 index:: 25
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(Or
 aclePreparedStatement.java:1681)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePrep
 aredStatement.java:3280)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePrepar
 edStatement.java:3368)
    at skypark.InsertusrProf.InsTable(InsertusrProf.java:99)
    at skypark.InsertusrProf.main(InsertusrProf.java:138)
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please answer this if you know the solution....
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at
 index:: 25
```

Means, your `ps.set....` not matching with number of `?`

You have total 30 ? but only 24 ps.Set.... statements.